# How can i use Empty String to terminate?

Tags: java, string

I just want to follow this condition, but the problem is that when i enter the empty, it will be continue loop infinity.

Please Enter either S (supply) or R (replenish) followed by ID and quantity.

```
R p122 10
```

New Stock-level for p125 (Pedal) is 18

```
S p905 20
```

No part found with ID p905

Empty String (to terminate)

Display the final.

I also try the following code, but it couldn't work

```
if (n.equals("")){
     code 
}
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class TestPart {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    Part[] part = new Part[5];
    part[0] = new Part("p122", "Chain", 48, 12.5 );
    part[1] = new Part("p123", "Chain Guard", 73, 22.0 );
    part[2] = new Part("p124", "Crank", 400, 11.5 );
    part[3] = new Part("p125", "Pedal", 38, 6.5 );
    part[4] = new Part("p126", "Handlebar", 123, 9.50 );



    Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);


    String n;
    String id;
    int qty;

    System.out.print("Please Enter either S(supply) or R(replenish) followed by ID and quantity:\n");

    int a = 0;
    do
    {
        n = src.next();
        id= src.next();
        qty= src.nextInt();

        boolean found = false;

        for(int i = 0; i< part.length; i++)
        {
            if(part[i].getID().equals(id))
            {
                found = true;
                String name = part[i].getName();
                int stockLevel = part[i].getStockLevel();

                if(id.equals(part[i].getID()) && n.charAt(0) == 'S')
                {
                    double amount = part[i].supply(qty);
                    if(amount>0){
                        System.out.println("New Stock-level for " + part[i].getID() + "(" + part[i].getName() + ") is " + part[i].getStockLevel());
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("New Stock-level for " + part[i].getID() + "(" + part[i].getName() + ") is not available" );
                    }

                }
                else if (id.equals(part[i].getID()) && n.charAt(0) == 'R')
                {
                    part[i].replenish(qty);
                    System.out.println("New Stock-level for " + part[i].getID() + "(" + part[i].getName() + ") is " + part[i].getStockLevel());
                }

            }

        }

        if (found == false)
            {
                System.out.println("No part found with ID " + id );
            }

        System.out.println("");
        for(int i=0; i<part.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(part[i].getID()+ "\t"+part[i].getName()+"\t"+part[i].getStockLevel()+"\t"+part[i].getUnitPrice() );
        }

        }while(a ==0);  


}
```

Comment: When exactly do you want to terminate your program? If no id is found??

Comment: Are you looking for the `break` statement?  What, exactly, did you try? (You showed an `if` statement but it just says `code` in the body; what did you try for `code`?)

Comment: Well   when i don't type anything (eg. id , n ,and qty) and it will display my final list directly.

Comment: Here is my trying: if (n.equals("")){
 a=2;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to terminate when the input line is empty

```
do{ 
String line = src.nextLine();
    String []  inputs = null;
    if(!line.matches("\\s*")){
        String n ;
        String id ;
        int qty;

        inputs = line.split(" ");
        if(inputs.length ==3)
        {
           n = inputs[0];
           id = inputs[1];
           qty  = (int) Integer.parseInt(inputs[2]);
        }
        else if(inputs.length ==2) 
        {
             id = inputs[0];
             qty  = (int) Integer.parseInt(inputs[1]);
        }

       // Your Logic

}
else
break;
}while(a==0)
```

Comment: 1. i just want to type in together (eg. S p122 10  in the one line)

Comment: when n will be empty what will be the standerd input like? or it will just be an empty line?

Comment: when i press the Enter button, it will be continuously display empty but it doesn't  display my final list

Comment: You should go one step ahead. First check if you can take the input as a line and then check if you can terminate from the loop by pressing enter. If the input is not an empty string,do the logical staff; otherwise break from the loop

Comment: but there are different input type ( int and string). so what should i fix that?

Comment: if input is like (eg: p122 10) then the inputs[] size will be 2 and if input is like (eg: S p905 20) inputs[] size will be 3. You can use these conditions.

Comment: Oh it just set in 3 size. another problem, when i follow your code, it works for empty part and display my list, but i can't type any code (eg S p122 10) and display the error with me

Comment: Yes, I have seen the code. and I have updated my code for you to understand better

Comment: it is same problem when i type any detail , it displays Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at SectionA.TestPart.main(TestPart.java:33)  . The problem is the( inputs = n.split(" "); )

Comment: String n is null, your input is in String line. Try, line.split(" " ).

Comment: but it will affect my id as well because it want me to change n and id are null and qty is 0. i update the code from these.

Comment: Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is:

```
  a = 0;
  do {
    // ...
  }while(a ==0);
```

that's why it loop infinitively.

Comment: So how can i change it?